Flutter conditional import for Android and Web app
I have a problem integrating payment gateway-related packages into my Flutter app. The app is targeted at two platforms:  Android and Web
I am using the RevenueCat package for the Android app and Stripe for the Web. There is a service facade that hides this from the rest of the app.  In the service class I am using the following conditional import.
import '../repository/dummy/dummy_purchase_repository.dart' if (dart.library.io) '../repository/revenuecat/revenue_cat_purchases.dart' if (dart.library.html) '../../repository/stripe/stripe_purchase_repository.dart';

This compiles fine for the web, but when I try to compile for Android I get the following error
Invalid depfile: D:\Ian\Documents\github\good_day\.dart_tool\flutter_build\61995fbac7f59d1b417808c42764f11c\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\Ian\Documents\github\good_day\.dart_tool\flutter_build\61995fbac7f59d1b417808c42764f11c\kernel_snapshot.d
/C:/Users/Ian/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_stripe_web-5.1.0/lib/src/widgets/payment_element.dart:2:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui_web' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ui_web' is imported through these packages:

    package:good_day => package:flutter_stripe_web => package:flutter_web_plugins => dart:ui_web
    package:good_day => package:flutter_stripe_web => dart:ui_web

Any suggestions?

My mistake...
The conditional import does work,  but I had a reference to another part of the Stripe package for UI widgets that needed to be translated to use conditional imports.
